# CSS draw shapes with shadow

Tags: html, css

I need to draw shapes as shown here in the Fiddle page http://jsfiddle.net/wNhjb/824/ with shadow, but shadow seems around the box not around the shape.

```
#shape {
   height: 0; 
   width: 200px;
   border-top: 50px solid blue;
   border-right: 50px solid transparent;
   box-shadow: 6px 6px 3px rgb(22,73,134); 
}
```

How can use the above code to get proper result.

Comment: Your code created box (using border). Shadow is applied to that box.

Comment: may be drop-shadow is more what your looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 'filter:drop-shadow()' instead.

```
#shape {
   height: 0; 
   width: 200px;
   border-top: 50px solid blue;
   border-right: 50px solid transparent;
   //box-shadow: 6px 6px 3px rgb(22,73,134); 
   filter: drop-shadow(6px 6px 3px gray);
}
```

updated fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/wNhjb/826/

Comment: `filter` is not implemented in IE. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter